# chrome: fail to load resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was building a chrome extension and my code (or the part of code which returns an error) looks something like this:

```
function callback(item) {
        for (key in item){
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                (function (i) {

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: some https webpage,
                    data: some data in string format,
                    success: function(info){

                        var $html = $(info);
                        var $blockquote = $html.find("blockquote");
                    }
                    }); // end of ajax
                })(key);
            }
        }
    }

}

function retrieve(fn) {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(fn);
}

retrieve(callback);
```

and it returns this (on the console):

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://mnnhocoeemolfdehajadghogfffnkiem/images/bnr.gif

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://mnnhocoeemolfdehajadghogfffnkiem/images/sp.gif

I've tried disabling other extensions and changing my file names, but those didn't work..
Can anyone help?? : (

Edit:
Here's my manifest file.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "schedule",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "checks berkeley schedule",
  "permissions": [
    "https://telebears.berkeley.edu/enrollment-osoc/*",
    "http://schedule.berkeley.edu/*/",
    "http://osoc.berkeley.edu/",
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon.png"
    },
   "default_popup": "schedule.html",
   "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.1.js", "schedule.js"]
  },

  "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not about your Javascript code. It is about files that you define somewhere (for example in the `manifest.json`) and that do not really exist in your extension folder, so Chrome tries to retrieve them and fails, causing the errors.

Look in your `manifest.json` file and search for some string with "images/bnr.gif" and "images/sp.gif". That's the part of code that causes these errors.

**UPDATE:** Maybe you are using that files inside an HTML page, maybe `options.html` or `schedule.html`. Check out all your .html files.

Comment: If this doesn't fix it please post your manifest.json

Comment: Hmm weird, because I don't use any of those files.. Anyways, I posted my manifest.json!

Comment: Thanks! but I really don't use any of those files anywhere in my code :( and my code works just fine if I replace that jquery portion with something else.. This is the weirdest bug I've ever encountered..

Comment: I don't know why but it started working with a constructor.. but when I add find(), it returns the exact same error... :P

Comment: Without seeing the code idk what to say :\

Comment: I found another posting with the same question but thanks! :)